# Editor automatically closes when running interactive rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-interactive-rebase

I'm trying to squash 40+ commits together in a branch I'm working on using interactive rebase. My chosen editor in git is vscode. When I run the command:

```
git rebase -i <commit>
```

I briefly see the file to edit appear in vscode, but then it automatically closes. It renames the file from "git-rebase-todo" to "git-rebase-todo (deleted from disk)" and then closes the tab.

Why is this happening? What are my options?

Answer (score 5):

The vscode forks (spawns) a new process. The original one exits and confuses git, as for git exiting editor means that job is done. rebase tmp file `git-rebase-todo` is deleted by git,what is indicated by vscode.

To fix that, update git config to use start vscode in the `wait` mode:

```
git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have to also pass a flag to `code` to make sure it spawns a new instance, instead of using the already-running one?

Comment: the `-w` implicitly creates a new window

Comment: ok but you did not include any `-w`.  Are you saying `-w` is the same as `--wait` ?

Comment: `-w` === `--wait`